# Does Log4j2 and SLF4J MDC get along?

Tags: log4j2, slf4j-api, finatra

Using Finatra, I'm trying to activate `traceID` logging, but nothing ends up in Log4J2 output.

[Finatra](https://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/logging/mdc.html) supports SLF4J MDC.
[SLF4J MDC](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html) is supposed to support Log4J (2?).
[Log4J2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) is supposed to support MDC and SLF4J.

But in the end, the MDC data is always empty reaching the message construction.

I tested with Logback as the log implementation and I had the MDC logged correctly, and [it is actually relying on SLF4J MDC](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/qos-ch/logback/-/blob/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/LoggingEvent.java?L405).
I do have to use log4J2 here (cannot be questioned).

Is this just not working because Log4J2 does not work correctly with SLF4J MDC?

To get it to work with Finatra, I just have to remove the `LoggingMDCFilter` which pretty must only replaces the `MDCAdapter` with the `FinagleMDCAdapter` [own implementation](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/twitter/finatra/-/blob/inject/inject-mdc/src/main/scala/com/twitter/inject/logging/FinagleMDCAdapter.scala), backed by Finagle `Contexts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed in your question [`FinagleMDCInitializer`](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/blob/develop/inject/inject-mdc/src/main/scala/org/slf4j/FinagleMDCInitializer.scala) replaces the MDC used by the logging backend with its own.

Logback uses SLF4J as their internal API (i.e. just Logback) so it will work with any `MDCAdapter` implementation installed, but all the remaining SLF4J backends won't.

The same hack that permits Logback to work with Finagle can be used in Log4j2 Core. Log4j2 Core is a native implementation of Log4j2 API and it will work with any implementation of [`ThreadContextMap`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ThreadContextMap.html).

We want to use a `ThreadContextMap` implementation that delegates all methods to SLF4J's `MDC`. Fortunately such an implementation is included in the [Apache Log4j2 API to SLF4J Adapter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j) (another implementation of the Log4j2 API). So we can use the following trick:

- add both `log4j-core` and `log4j-to-slf4j` to your application's classpath. Since now there are two implementations of the Log4j2 API available, we need to specify the one we actually want to use. We can do it by adding a file called `log4j2.component.properties` at the root of your classpath with:

  ```
  log4j2.loggerContextFactory = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory
  ```
- in the same property file we specify that we want to use the `ThreadContextMap` implementation included in `log4j-to-slf4j`:

  ```
  log4j2.threadContextMap = org.apache.logging.slf4j.MDCContextMap
  ```
- I assume that you already have `log4j-slf4j-impl` (Apache SLF4J to Log4j2 API Adapter) on your classpath.

**Remark**: the proposed solution assumes that `FinagleMDCInitializer` is called **as soon** as possible. SLF4J does not have an equivalent of the `log4j2.threadContexMap` property to force it to use a concrete implementation of `MDCAdapter`. **Until** Finagle replaces the implementations, your application will use the `MDCAdapter` from `log4j-slf4j-impl` that delegates everything to the `ThreadContextMap`, that delegates everything to `MDCAdapter`, ... You'll have a guaranteed StackOverflow.

**Edit:** If you end up with a StackOverflow, you can:

- start with NOOP `ThreadContextMap`:

  ```java
  log4j2.threadContextMap = org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.NoOpThreadContextMap
  ```
- replace the `MDCAdapter` and `ThreadContextMap` all in one place:

  ```
   // Replace the `MDCAdapter`
   MDCInitializer.init();
   try {
       // Change ThreadContextMap implementation
       System.setProperty("log4j2.threadContextMap", "org.apache.logging.slf4j.MDCContextMap");
       // Properties are cached so a reload is needed
       PropertiesUtil.getProperties().reload();
       // Call ThreadContext.init()
       final Method method = ThreadContext.class.getDeclaredMethod("init");
       method.setAccessible(true);
       method.invoke(null);
   } catch (SecurityException | ReflectiveOperationException | IllegalArgumentException  e) {
       logger.warn("ThreadContext reinitialization failed.", e);
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the details answer Piotr, but doing this I would get the famous `log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j` error. I will try with rgoers'

Comment: @brisssou: that happens if Log4j2 API uses the `LoggerContextFactory` from `log4j-to-slf4j`, which is not the case (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/518c3f32dd2e3cc347ac5d4c066b7f34cf7462d4/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLoggerFactory.java#L68)). This solution is far from being proper (and neither is the hack used by Finagle), but this exception does not occur (I tested the solution).

Comment: how/where did you call FinagleMDCInitializer so you don't have the StackOverflow? I don't find a proper first-before-everything entry/callback in `HttpServer`

Comment: I didn't actually use the full Finagle environment, but a minimal example class. That was probably too much minimal.

Comment: I eventually got it creating another main object, calling the TwitterServer main one.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to Piotr's answer.

In accordance with SLF4J's SPI, Log4j 2 provides its own `StaticMDCBinder` class. This returns Log4j's `MDCAdapter` that acts as a bridge between the MDC API and Log4j's `ThreadContextMap`.  When Finatra replaces that `MDCAdapter` the binding is lost so nothing stored in the MDC will make it into the `ThreadContextMap`. Note that this is necessary because Log4j does not actually use the SLF4J API anywhere except in the adapters.

I believe a better approach than what Piotr suggests would be to modify `FinagleMDCInitializer` to detect that Log4j-core is present and exit and then have Finatra provide its own `ThreadContextMap` implementation. In this case only the `log4j2.thradContextMap` property would need to be provided to reference the custom class and the use of log4j-to-slf4j would not be necessary.

If you do provide a custom `ThreadContextMap` then the call to `MDCInitializer` would be unnecessary and you wouldn't really need to make any changes to it as they would only be there to prevent `MDCInitializer` from breaking the binding with Log4j.

Comment: I tried implementing class that was both an `MDCAdapter` and a `ThreadContextMap` and initialize it from a Filter, the same way `LoggingMDCFilter` does. Somehow I can `put` values but then getting them (from `getImmutableMapOrNull`) it always get a `null` and them I'm lost.

Comment: If you only need the Finagle MDC data in your logging message, you can also implement a [`ContextDataProvider`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/ContextDataProvider.html) and register it as a Java Service. `LogEvent`s collect context data from all context data providers (usually there is only one that uses `ThreadContext`, but you can have many).

Comment: A ThreadContextMap implementation should not implement MDCAdapter. Instead it should be registered using the `log4j2.threadContextMap` System Property. Once you do that it will be used by all of Log4j automatically.